# Enterprise Architect: Setting run state from initial attribute values when creating instance

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am on Enterprise Architect 13.5, creating a deployment diagram. I am defining our servers as nodes, and using attributes on them so that I can specify their details, such as `Disk Controller = RAID 5` or `Disks = 4 x 80 GB`.

When dragging instances of these nodes onto a diagram, I can select "Set Run State" on them and set values for all attributes I have defined - just like it is done in the deployment diagram in the EAExample project:

[image: Instance with attributes defined via Set Run State]

Since our design will have several servers using the same configuration, my plan was to use the "initial value" column in the attribute definition on the node to specify the default configuration so that all instances I create automatically come up with reasonable values, and when the default changes, I would only change the Initial Values on the original node instead of having to go to all instances:

[image: Defining Initial Values on the Node]

My problem is that even though I define initial values, all instances I create do not show *any* values when I drag them onto the diagram. Only by setting the Run State on each instance, I can get them to show the values I want:

[image]

Is this expected behavior? Btw, I can reproduce the same using classes and instances of them, so this is not merely a deployment diagram issue.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated! I'm also thankful if you can describe a better way to achieve the same result with EA, in case I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I guess it's just that way. Scripting might be a solution. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to either write a script to assist with it or even create an add-in to bring in more automation. Scripting is easier to implement but you need to run the script manually (which however can add the values in a batch for newly created diagram objects). Using an add-in could do this on element creation if you hook to `EA_OnPostNewElement`.

What you need to do is to first get the classifier of the object. Using

```
Repository.GetElementByID(object.ClassifierID)
```

will return that. You then can check the attributes of that class and make a list of those with an initial value. Finally you add the run states of the object by assigning `object.RunState` with a crude string. E.g. for  `a != 33` it would be

```
@VAR;Variable=a;Value=33;Op=!=;@ENDVAR;
```

Just join as many as you need for multiple run states.

Comment: thanks! Will try that if I don't find any other solution. However, isn't that supposed to work automatically? Else, what would be the purpose of "initial value"?

Comment: The run state is, as the name says, a run state. As such it can take any value during run time. And you show objects in a context at any given time. Not only when they are instantiated.

Comment: hm, ok - that might indicate though that I am not using EA in the intended way. Do you have any other ideas how to achieve what I wanted, i.e. define default computer configurations that I can reuse and adapt in different diagrams?

Comment: Well, the above isn't that bad. If you have an object it represents something concrete. Now, what is your interpretation of "reuse"? I suggest you come up with a different question since this comment is not intended to solve additional issues.

Comment: It's still my original problem how to best model this, but I admit I phrased the questions so that it focus very much on the solution using attributes. I'll open a new question.

Comment: New question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328217/how-to-model-reusable-computer-configurations-in-enterprise-architect-deployment

Comment: Will look tomorrow. Basically I have written about that in my BA book :-)