# How to model reusable computer configurations in Enterprise Architect deployment model

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am on Enterprise Architect 13.5, creating a deployment diagram. I would like to define templates of servers that are always the same, e.g. with a specific processor, RAM, hard disks, and ideally also operating system.

I would then like to reuse this type of template in several deployment diagrams where we are using the same types of computers. When we decide to change the types of computers (e.g. newer OS or more RAM), I would like to update a single place only and all computers instantiated from the template should update automatically.

What I have tried:

- Model my template as a node
- Define the properties (RAM, processor, etc.) as the nodes' attributes with an initial value
- Adding OS as a child execution environment to the node
- Creating instances of this node whenever I want to use that type of computer in a diagram

However, this does not achieve the desired result since the initial attribute values are not shown on the instance, and also the execution environment is not part of the instance.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are many ways which would be favored by yet unknown circumstances. However, here's a way with tagged values. If you add a TV to a Node and instantiate it, it will be inherited and you can override the value (here 2G instead of 1G).

[image]

I have turned on to show tags in the diagram

[image]

So that's probably a way. However, this is EA. When you create a new instance you will not see the inherited tag:

[image]

To make the inherited tag visible you have to turn it on in the element Features&Properties/...Visibility context (make sure the Tags option is checked as well):

[image]

Which then yields [image]

Comment: As a final shameless self plug: you might look into my book "EA for the Business Analyst" (http://liquit.biz/brain/books.html) where I elaborate on a way to show exactly that scenario in a more general way.

Comment: Thanks, that works better although the option using attributes formats more nicely (would prefer to avoid the "tags" and the "::Device1", but what the hell). Btw, I needed to turn on showing Tags as well, only Inherited Tags does not work. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yaaa, it's EA. This tool could be soo much better if they'd concentrate on doing the basic things right rather than adding bells and whistles nobody actually needs.